# Javascript error in IE 7

Tags: javascript

Hoping you can help me...
I'm getting the following javascript error in IE7:

> Expected Identifier, String, or Number

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.full',
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just a tip for Visual Studio users: when you have such errors or other characters misplaced that you don't know about, clicking on `Format Document` often throws an exception with details at which line is in error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove , from line  `itemSelector : '.full',`.

comma after last key value pair in JavaScript object will through exception in IE 7.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.full'
  });
});
</script>
```